# architechture when getting objects from server side

Tags: sockets, node.js, socket.io

When wanting to get something from the server, I've done something a couple of times that just feels wrong, and my question is if there's some better way to do it.

On the clientside I do;

```
socket.emit('getToy');
```

And on the serverside:

```
socket.on('getToy', function(){
   socket.emit('newtoy', thetoy);
});
```

It feels like there should be some way to do;

```
socket.emit('getToy', function(thetoy){
    //play with the toy
});
```

What are the best practices to do in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `emit` function client side, pass a function as the last parameter and it can be RPC'd from the server.

#### Client

```
socket.emit('getToy', function(thetoy) {
  // play
});
```

#### Server

```
socket.on('getToy', function(fn) {
  fn(thetoy);
});
```

It's on the [socket.io website](http://socket.io/#how-to-use) under 'Sending and getting data'.